# Any recommendations on joists for weight bearing?

Tags: wood, ceiling, floor

I am building a room (14 x 25) in my barn. I intend to stack hay on the top of the ceiling of this room. The estimated weight of the hay is 24,000 pounds. The joists will run the 14' length. What thickness of lumber (example 2 x 6) should I use and what should the spacing be?

Answer (score 2):

68.57 Pounds per square foot if evenly distributed - call it 70 (or 75) and pull up a [calculator](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/arch264/calculators/example8.1/) (or drop by your lumberyard and have them run it on their I-joist software, which might well be the most affordable solution.) Or hire an engineer.

Underbuilt haylofts do have a tendency to demonstrate that they are underbuilt; so don't underbuild it.

Comment: Aye, 12 tons of weight requires more than just some internet recommendation.

Comment: Plus, that kind of load requires looking at the walls and supporting structure to determine if they can handle it, even if the joists are sized properly.